# Active Record: Rounding off 0.00 to 0.0

Tags: mysql, rails-activerecord

I am using Mysql and the column data type is Decimal(10,2). When the data stored is something like 35.43 it comes back as it is but the problem stems when the data stored is 100.00, at the time of retrieving, Active Record implicitly converts into 100.0.

Monkey patching Active Record remains an option but keen to know if there are better ways of solving it?

Comment: sounds like something printf can solve.

Comment: Lol, it can't. We are looking at retrieving data in models.

Comment: There is no difference in the model between 100.00 and 100.0. So this should really be just a presentation layer problem.